# Google Script - how to convert every value of object range (getdisplayvalueS) to lowercase

Tags: javascript, arrays, lowercase

I would like to convert all the data in the data range that i took on one sheet and copy it to another sheet but as lower case
I tried this

```js
var values=ss.getSheetByName("name").getRange("A1:A16").getDisplayValues();  
ss.getSheetByName("name2").getRange("A1:A16).setValues(
    values).toLowerCase();
```

but it doesn't work - only works with one value (i.e. displayvalue.toLowerCase() )

does anybody know how I can apply this lowercase to every value in the object array?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- `values` retrieved by `getDisplayValues()` is 2 dimensional array.
- `setValues()` returns "Range".

The modified script which reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
var values=ss.getSheetByName("name").getRange("A1:A16").getDisplayValues();
var convertedValues = values.map(function(e){return [e[0].toLowerCase()]}); // Added
ss.getSheetByName("name2").getRange("A1:A16).setValues(convertedValues); // Modified
```

#### References :

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))